# how to write an integer to a file (the difference between fprintf and fwrite)

Tags: c, fwrite, printf

I've been trying to write an integer to a file (open mode is w).
fprintf wrote it correctly but fwrite wrote gibberish:

```
int length;
char * word = "word";

counter = strlen(word);
fwrite(&length, sizeof(int), 1, file);
fwrite(word, sizeof(char), length, file);
```

and the result in the file is:

> word

but if I use fprintf instead, like this:

```
int length;
char * word = "word";

counter = strlen(firstWord);
fprintf(file, "%d", counter);
fwrite(word, sizeof(char), length, file);
```

I get this result in the file:

> 4word

can anyone tell what I did wrong?
thanks!

update: I would eventually like to change the writing to binary (I will open the file in wb mode), will there be a difference in my implementation?

Comment: length is uninitialised.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`fprintf` writes a string. `fwrite` writes bytes. So in your first case, you're writing the bytes that represent an integer to the file; if its value is "4", the four bytes will be in the non-printable ASCII range, so you won't see them in a text editor. But if you look at the size of the file, it will probably be 8, not 4 bytes.

Comment: so if I want to write an integer in a binary mode I should use fwrite, but if I write to the file textually I should use fprintf?

Answer (score 1):

Using `printf()` converts the integer into a series of characters, in this case `"4"`. Using `fwrite()` causes the actual bytes comprising the integer value to be written, in this case, the 4 bytes for the characters `'w', 'o', 'r',` and `'d'`.