# C code Image to text and back not working

Tags: c, image, file, pointers

I want to read an image, say image1 as a string and convert it back as image2. Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

  int length;
  FILE *image1,*image2;
  image1= fopen("image1.jpg", "rb");    
  fseek(image1, 0, SEEK_END);         
  length= ftell(image1);           
  rewind(image1);             

  char file_data[length+1];
  fread(file_data, length, 1, image1);

  image2 = fopen ("image2.jpg", "wb");  
  fprintf (image2, "%s", file_data);

  fclose(image1);
  fclose(image2);

  return 0;
}
```

However, the image2 that is getting created is not opening. How do I rectify this?

Comment: Use `fwrite` instead of `fprintf`.

Comment: That helped. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552907/how-to-write-an-integer-to-a-file-the-difference-between-fprintf-and-fwrite 
explains pretty well the difference between `fprintf` and `fwrite`.